# How to set QImage pixel colour for an RGB888 image in Qt

Tags: qt, rgb, qimage, pixel-manipulation

I have an RGB888 format qImage defined as follows:

```
myQrgb = QImage(img_in, width, height, QImage::Format_RGB888);
```

I wish to alter specific pixel values, so I followed the example [here](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#id-d25776d3-e0c4-43bf-b8e6-e6095530d501), like so:

```
QRgb value = qRgb(0, 0, 0);
myQrgb.setPixel(i, j, value);
```

This, however, always produces a segmentation fault regardless of the values of i and j (e.g. i = j = 2).

I am guessing it is because I am incorrectly using `QRgb` to manipulate pixels in a `QImage::Format_RGB888`. What should I do instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are few things you need to confirm:

1. According to [QImage constructor](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#memberSection) you're using, make sure `img_in` remains valid throughout the life span of `QImage` object. By the way, `QImage` destructor will not delete your data (`img_in`).
2. If the pixel position you're setting is not valid coordinate, `setPixel()`'s behavior is undefined.

I suspect the first case, `img_in` is probably vanishing from `QImage`. You may want to try to create a `QImage` using other constructor like `QImage(10, 10, QImage::Format_RGB888)` and play with `setPixel()`.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem; I was not aware that img_in was in fact just a pointer to the underlying data it was referencing.

Comment: According to Qt documentation, `setPixel()` is expensive for large images.

Answer (score 6):

I think the problem may be more related to the `img_in` data with which you are initializing the image. Are you sure that data is valid?

The following example successfully paints a white square with a black square in the corner.

```
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  QImage img(100, 100, QImage::Format_RGB888);
  img.fill(QColor(Qt::white).rgb());

  for (int x = 0; x < 10; ++x) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 10; ++y) {
      img.setPixel(x, y, qRgb(0, 0, 0));
    }
  }

  QLabel l;
  l.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
  l.show();

  return app.exec();
}
```